# webpack-dev-server not searching for available port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

after upgrading to webpack5, when trying to run second webpack-dev-server instance it fail because the port 8080 already in use while webpack4 found another available port.

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8080
webpack: 5.24.4
node.js: 14.16.0
webpack-dev-server: 3.11.2[image]